# Local Transition with duration in Svelte not working

Tags: svelte, svelte-component, svelte-transition

I am trying to animate list elements sliding in, one after another using this code:

```
<li class="list-element" in:slide|local={{duration:1000}}>
```

but somehow it doesn't seem to transition the list elements. When I remove "local" it works, but not one after another.
What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this problem?

Edit: Example
You can paste this into the svelte REPL, it will show the problem.

```html
<script>
    import {slide} from "svelte/transition"
let data = [...Array(25).keys()];
    let withLocal = true;
</script>

<button on:click={()=>withLocal = !withLocal}>
    Toggle Working / not working
</button>
{#if withLocal} 
<ul class="list">
    {#each data as i}
    <li in:slide|local={{duration:1000}}>{i}</li>
    {/each}
</ul>
{:else}
<ul class="list">
    {#each data as i}
    <li in:slide={{duration:1000}}>{i}</li>
    {/each}
</ul>
{/if}

<style>
.list
    {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
</style>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a full example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Yup, added an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of `local` is:

> Local transitions only play when the block they belong to is created or destroyed, not when parent blocks are created or destroyed.

So setting this flag in no way makes the items correlate with each other. I do not know if there is a simple approach to sliding in the items individually, but setting a delay based on the index gets you most of the way there for initial rendering. Of course the transition needs to be triggered somehow, e.g. by setting the source data with a delay/in `onMount`.

```html
<ul class="list">
    {#each data as i}
        <li in:slide={{ duration: 100, delay: i * 50 }}>{i}</li>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/c7f88cd52e744df186570b39de4d352b?version=3.48.0)

One problem is still that newly added items would have an unnecessary delay on their fade-in. One workaround might be to use a data field or separate lookup table instead of just the array index.

Answer (score 0):

If the unnecessary delay of later added items was a problem, an alternative approach to setting the delay based on the index in the `#each` block could be to add the items with a delay to the data array in the beginning. The "delayed animation" would then run when the component is mounted and every later added item is transitioned in as well and instantly
**Edit** If items are added during the initial "filling process" this will lead to errors, so this version is not recommended

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/207e76d06c4e4c00a24e54f1e0b08977?version=3.48.0)

```
<script>
    import {slide} from "svelte/transition"

    let data = []

    const base = [...Array(11).keys()]
    const delay = 75

    base.forEach((elem, index) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            data = [...data, elem]
        }, delay * index)
    })

</script>

<div>
    
<button on:click={() => data = [...data, data.length]}>Add item</button>

<ul class="list">
    {#each data as d}
    <li in:slide={{duration:150}}>{d}</li>
    {/each}
</ul>

</div>

<style>
    .list
    {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I considered this as well but would not recommend it. Animations like this should be only visual, because if any interactivity is added, that could lead to odd side effects like not all items being saved or new items being added in the middle of the list while it is still updating.